# Zend Translate inside action helper

Tags: zend-framework

How to pass Zend Translate to Action helper?

Thanks.

Comment: Ok i have found solution with Zend_Registry. But how to add translated work inside form element label?

It isn't working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Labels are transleted by default.

Comment: I'm using custom labels. I was passing static array before started to use Zend Translate